# django: is @csrf_exempt a good idea?

Tags: python, django

I have an endpoint which is supposed to work like an API:

```
/reset/<ID>
```

This will be called via ajax/angular from a separate client (CORS issues already addressed).

Now, if I just publish the endpoint in `urls.py`, I get an error:

```
403 Forbidden
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

The reasons are clear to me.

So I investigated and found this @csrf_exempt decorator. With it, it works...but is it ok to do it like this?
The request does not follow a request-response cycle, the client may send this reset at any time - so I would not know how to send the `X-CSRF-Token` header to the client...so maybe in the end it's the only way to go?

Comment: How do you authenticate the client? A CSRF token protects against abuse of the information that is sent on each request by a user or browser agent, such as a cookie that contains the user's session id. If you don't use any such information, you can safely use `@csrf_exempt`.

Comment: This will be used for resetting the password only, and comes with a login code which is valid one tim only. Thus there can't be a real authentication...the ID is supposed to be unique and not guessable....really copy pasting from other's solutions....

Comment: @knbk if you like you can provide your comment as an answer, and I will accept it. Your comment actually opened my eyes as to how to correctly do it, which has nothing to do with csrf_exempt, but with having a proper API :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you authenticate the user. A CSRF token protects against abuse of information that is sent on each request by a user or browser agent, such as a cookie that contains the user's session id. If you don't use any such information, you can safely use `@csrf_exempt`.